# PDFLaTeX basic installation in windows for R pdf output for slow internet

Tags: pdftex, r

I have a windows operating system. I'm using R statistical software. I have to output a R MarkDown file into pdf. This can be done by PDFTeX which requires installation from MiKTeX.

R suggests that I should do complete installation rather than basic installation. But my internet connection is not reliable to complete the complete installation. So I have installed the basic installation.

Is there any way to make this basic installation run to give the pdf output in R?

I have never worked with LaTeX before. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer.

Installed the basic installation.

Then found the setup file in the path 'C:/Users/User_name/temp/MikTex/***.exe'. Installed it.

Then went to RStudio software, tools>global options>Sweave. Changed the 'Typset LaTeX into PDF using:' to pdfLaTeX.

Ran the knit PDF command for a R Markdown file and it asked for the installation of the package. Clicked ok and the package got installed  automatically.

Then the PDF file got generated!